# React Router 4 + history.push firing PUSH and POP

Tags: reactjs, react-router, history.js, react-router-v4

So I have set up the following route in my app:

```
<Router history={history}>      
    <div>
      <Route path={'/'} exact component={Home} />
      <Route path={'/cachaca/:bottle'} component={BottlePage} />
      <PublicRoute authed={this.state.authed} exact path={'/login'} component={Login} />
      <PublicRoute authed={this.state.authed} exact path={'/register'} component={Register} />
      <PrivateRoute authed={this.state.authed} path={'/dashboard'} component={Dashboard} />
    </div>
</Router>
```

In different parts of the app, I programatically navigate around the app with history.push like so:

```
history.push({
  pathname: '/',
  search: '?startRange='+ startRange + '&endRange='+ endRange + '&maker=0'
})
```

The odd thing is that when that code runs, it triggers two actions - a PUSH and a POP causing the app to navigate twice. This is what we get from the history listener log after a single push:

```
The current URL is /?startRange=0&endRange=31&maker=0
The last navigation action was PUSH
The current URL is /?startRange=0&endRange=31&maker=0
The last navigation action was POP
```

The query params are getting properly stored and everything else seems to be working fine, but I was wondering what could be creating this problem so that my user doesn't have to back twice to go to where he actually was supposed to.

Incidentally, here is how I conjure up the history 'plugin':

```
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'

const history = createHistory() 

history.listen((location, action) => {
  console.log(`The current URL is ${location.pathname}${location.search}${location.hash}`)
  console.log(`The last navigation action was ${action}`)
})

export default history
```

There is also another instance where the push changes the url location bar but doesn't actually navigate anywhere but I'll save that for another question.

Am I doing something wrong? Appreciate any help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to mix and match react-router v2 and v4, which are very different. See the comments [here](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4059).

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip! It's hard to keep track of what you are reading.While actual RR4 documentation is rather scarce, you could be reading an article here or a code snippet there and think it's related to RR4 when in reality it is not.

I'm going the context way and it seems to be working fine but I'll have to rearrange my app tree.

Thanks again!